# MVC3 Range validation when value is larger then zero

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a product order page where the minimum order is 2500. I want to use the Range annotation validation in the model to validate this, but I also need the user to be able to select 0 of this product if they don't want any.

Now I use:

```
[Display(Name = "Item1")]
[Range(1000, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "You need to order minimum {1} of Item1")]
public int OrderedItem1{ get; set; }
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this without creating a custom validator?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use the regular expression validation attribute.

```
[RegularExpression(@"SomeRegExpression", ErrorMessage = "Min order error")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I could do this using this regular expression validation attribute:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:0|\d{5,}|[1-9]\d\d\d)$", ErrorMessage = "You need to order minimum 1000 of Item1")]
```

Thanks to Ryand Johnson for helping out.